# How to save the login content in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

However, because I am loading the web page in UIWebView by calling UIWebView's loadRequest, those techniques are not really applicable.

Any ideas how I can save the login content in web page so that on again app launch to save my login content in UIWebView page,

This url save login content:- http://aubonpain.mloyalconnect.com/microsite/

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll("input[type='password']")

For all textField use:   document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

NSString *userName = @"xyz";
NSString *password = @"abc";

if (userName.length != 0 && password.length != 0) {


    NSString *jsPassword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='password']\").value ='%@'", password];

    NSString *jsUsername = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='text']\"); \
                            for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", userName];

    [self.mywebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsUsername];
    [self.mywebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsPassword];
}
```

}

Comment: Tanks ManiaChamp
this url http://aubonpain.mloyalconnect.com/microsite/ save Login Content

Comment: @SaurabhGupta if it worked please mark it as right answer

Comment: This url save login content:- http://aubonpain.mloyalconnect.com/microsite/

Comment: @SaurabhGupta : Using document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']") you will get all the textField text then you can save the content of any textfield as your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following in couple of my live apps and they work quite well.

**Save cookies when you get response** :

```
- (void)saveCookiesToDefaults
{
    NSData *cookiesData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cookiesData forKey:@"SAVED_COOKIES"];
}
```

**Load cookies** :

```
- (void)loadCookies
{
    NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"SAVED_COOKIES"]];
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *newProperties = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:cookie.properties];
        NSDate *date = [newProperties objectForKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];
        if(date == nil)
            [newProperties setObject:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:100*12*30*60*60] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];
        else
            [newProperties setObject:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:100*12*30*60*60] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];
        NSHTTPCookie *newCookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:newProperties];
        [cookieStorage setCookie: newCookie];
        NSLog(@"%@",newCookie);
    }
}
```

**Clear cookies from session** :

```
- (void)clearCookies
{
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies])
    {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"SAVED_COOKIES"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

**Check if session exists** :

```
- (BOOL)hasExistingSession
{
    NSData *savedCookiesData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SAVED_COOKIES"];
    if(savedCookiesData == nil)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        NSArray *savedCookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedCookiesData];

        for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in savedCookies)
        {
            [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
        }

        NSLog(@"HAS EXISTING SESSION: %@", savedCookies.count ? @"YES" : @"NO");

        return savedCookies.count;
    }

}
```